# MS Visio Open() method throws an Exception in PHP script

Tags: php, exception, visio

I have a problem with my PHP script: I try to open a .vsd file with a php code. It works with a double click on file just fine, but the code throws an Exception and I can't understand why.
Here it is:

```
$visioApp = NULL;
try
{
    $visioApp = new COM("Visio.Application");
} 
try
{       
    if($visioApp->Documents == NULL)
    {
        echo("NULL");
    }
    $visioApp->Documents->Open("Drawing1.vsd");

}
catch(Exception $e)
{   
    echo("Error!!!!");
}

$visioDoc = $visioApp->Quit();
```

I become "Error!!!!" every time. Drawing1.vsd is in the same folder as the script.
Maybe someone has an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the exception message? You neglect to mention what what `$e->getMessage()` actually tells you

Comment: I just tried it. Hier is what I got: Description: This file name is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Visio will not look for files in the location of your script. See [Application.DrawingPaths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766182(v=office.15).aspx) property for an explanation of where it will look for files.

The simplest solution for you may be to append the file name to the working directory of your script, e.g.:

```
$visioApp->Documents->Open(getcwd() . "\\Drawing1.vsd");
```